# MigLayout aligns JSlider wrong

Tags: swing, miglayout

When adding a `JSlider` in a container with MigLayout, I've found that the slider is aligned to the bottom and adding some extra space:

```
import java.awt.Container;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;

public class SliderAlignOnMigLayout {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
        contentPane.setLayout(new MigLayout("debug"));
        contentPane.add(new JLabel("Slider:"));
        contentPane.add(new JSlider());

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

[image: Slider aligned wrong in MigLayout]

Have tested it on versions 4.2 and 5.0, on any standard look and feel (in Windows) plus Substance. Happens any time.

This seems to have been asked [in the MigLayout forums](http://migcalendar.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=3135), but the code posted works and so didn't get further answers. I've tried to post a report there but seems to be disabled, and the authors wrote that they'd be checking StackOverflow for providing support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The space is not there in MigLayout version 4.3. I am getting it in
MigLayout version 5.1.

This might be related to the fact that `JSpinner` may display values (only GTK look and feel) or labels. Maybe MigLayout takes possible labels into account when calculating bounds of a spinner. The following screenshots were taken with MigLayout 5.1.

The first screenshot shows a `JSpinner` with labels:

[image: JSlider with labels]

The second screenshot shows a `JSpinner` with a displayed 
value on GTK laf:

[image: JSpinner in GTK laf]

If we remove the value on GTK laf with

`UIManager.put("Slider.paintValue", false);`

then we get this screnshot:

[image]

Comment: Excellent.
I wasn't aware of version 4.3 since it never left snapshot state, and looking at the activity on version 5.1 (5 snapshots this past week), I hope that they're adding that unrelased fix on it.